# limit_req differ zones by time of day

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I want to limit requests to my service depending on the time of day.
It should be 4 r/s by night (21:00 - 06:59) and 1 r/s by day (07:00-20:59).
I could have 2 different `req_limit_zone` like

```
limit_req_zone $server_name zone=day:1m rate=1r/s;
limit_req_zone $server_name zone=night:1m rate=4r/s;
```

but how can I differ them in `limit_req` depending on the time of day?

The service behind nginx is an API wrapper for another service with limits described above. My service is written with `Flask-RESTful`, runs by `uWSGI` with a few processes, so it would be pretty painful to implement limiting logic and sync it between processes with something like `redis`.

Is it possible to configure nginx this way?
If it's not, are there any common workarounds? How do other services solve this task?
To be more specific, it should be a leaking bucket, so clients just wait for an answer without any errors like HTTP 429 Too Many Requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The answer

The key is to bind `limit_req_zone` and `map`.
There are two relevant notes about them in the docs. [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html):

> default *value*
>
> > sets the resulting value if the source value matches none of the specified variants. When `default` is not specified, the default resulting value will be an **empty string**.

and [limit_req_zone](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html):

> **limit_req_zone** *key* zone=name:size rate=rate;
>
> > Sets parameters for a shared memory zone that will keep states for various keys. In particular, the state stores the current number of excessive requests. The `key` can contain text, variables, and their combination. **Requests with an empty key value are not accounted**.

So one does simply use both *day* and *night* `limit_req_zone` with `$server_name` as *key* if it should work and with empty string if it shouldn't. And `map` will return either `$server_name` or empty string depending on the time of day.

```
map $date_gmt $day {  
    # 07:00-20:59 GMT  
    ~(0[7-9]|1[0-9]|20):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] $server_name;  
}

map $date_gmt $night {  
    # 21:00-06:59 GMT  
    ~(2[1-4]|0[0-6]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] $server_name;  
}

limit_req_zone $day zone=day_zone:1m rate=1r/s;
limit_req_zone $night zone=night_zone:1m rate=4r/s;

...

limit_req zone=day_zone burst=100;
limit_req zone=night_zone burst=100;
```

---

### Some notes about `req_limit`

At first attempt I tried to use mapped variable in `limit_req`, but nginx don't understand such syntax. Further more, at first glance `nginx -s reload` worked without any problem, but in fact there was no any reload and only `service nginx restart` showed an error (nginx version: 1.12.2). So I'd like to show how one **should not to do**:

```
limit_req_zone $server_name zone=day:1m rate=1r/s;
limit_req_zone $server_name zone=night:1m rate=4r/s;

map $date_gmt $time_of_day {  
    ~(0[7-9]|1[0-9]|20):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] day;  
    ~(2[1-4]|0[0-6]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] night;  
}

...

limit_req zone=$time_of_day burst=100;
```

---

### Some notes about *performance*

It's not the best solution because of double time checking on every request. There is option to have two separate nginx configs and switch them with something like cron. It would be ugly and buggy because you should remember to edit two configs, but it would work faster; I think this option should be used as a last resort. If there is an ability for horizontal scaling, it's better to load balance multiple servers.
In my case it's not a big deal: service gets just about 8k requests per hour (2.2 r/s).